# My NSFontDescriptor's having no effect; what's going on?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsfont

All right, I'm trying to use italics and serif on an `NSAttributedString`, but for some reason, the font traits have absolutely no effect.  I think I used them correctly (the `NSFontDescriptor` reference is not particularly well-written, in my opinion, so I don't know for sure).

```
    NSMutableAttributedString *pellString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]
                  initWithString:@"x2 – Dy2 = N"];
    NSFontSymbolicTraits varMask = NSFontModernSerifsClass | NSFontItalicTrait;
    NSDictionary *varSymbolic = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:
                                 [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:varMask] 
                                                            forKey:NSFontSymbolicTrait];
    NSDictionary *varAttrs = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:varSymbolic
                                                         forKey:NSFontTraitsAttribute];
    NSFontDescriptor *varDesc = [NSFontDescriptor fontDescriptorWithFontAttributes:varAttrs];
    NSFont *variables = [NSFont fontWithDescriptor:varDesc
                                              size:24];
    [pellString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:variables range:NSMakeRange(0, 12)];
```

When I NSLog `variables`, the `NSFont` object, I get the following:

```
"LucidaGrande 24.00 pt. P [] (0x7f9f43e18970) fobj=0x7f9f43e18b40, spc=7.59"
```

In other words, `NSFont` did not create a serif font like I asked, nor did it create an italic font (and I tried each of them independently, too, without the other).  Logging the `NSFontDescriptor` yielded the key-value pairs I put in there, so the problem must be at the step where the `NSFont` object is created.  My guess is that these are read-only properties, and I can't set them, only read them.  Am I reading this correctly?

If so, what would be the preferred way of specifying a generic serif font?  Or do I have to pick a specific one and deal with users possibly not having access to that font?

Comment: It may be that it requires an exact match based on a combination of what you gave and the defaults for other attributes (if the default font isn't a serif font, then nothing would match; Helvetica and Lucida Grande are the two logical defaults I can think of and they are both sans-serif).  You might need to use the `matchingFontDescriptorsWithMandatoryKeys:` method of `NSFontDescriptor` to return all possible fonts that match the few things that you specify.

Comment: Thank you @KevinGrant!  Based on your suggestion, I think I figured it out, and I wrote a [basic tutorial](http://www.offtonic.com/blog/?p=29) on it.  My equation looks pretty nice now. (:

Comment: @MauroBraunstein I know it's a few years too late, but I think there's a slightly different diagnosis: not necessarily `NSFontSymbolicTrait` being optional, but rather the font system requires an **exact match for the entire trait dictionary**, or it ignores **all** traits. I posed a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34688247/how-do-i-get-appkit-core-text-to-get-the-closest-matching-set-of-traits-instead). I'm not sure why it's completely ignoring the family name in your case, but it probably has to do with the Serif flag. Still stupid that it's not a nearest match...

Comment: And I could be wrong about the "not necessarily" part (it could be "in addition to"; I used Core Text instead of NSFont so I don't know if there are subtle differences between the two), but I guess it might help. I don't know if any of the serif fonts on your system actually have the `NSFontOldStyleSerifsClass` flag set on them if you query their descriptors directly from the NSFontCollection either; a quick test should confirm that though...

Comment: Hm, okay; all forms of Times New Roman do have `NSFontOldStyleSerifsClass` on them on my 10.11 machine; weird...