# How do I get AppKit/Core Text to get the closest matching set of traits instead of discarding the entire trait list when not exactly matched?

Tags: macos, cocoa, core-text

Given the following example program:

```
import Cocoa

let traits: [String: AnyObject] = [
    NSFontSymbolicTrait: (NSFontBoldTrait | NSFontItalicTrait),// | NSFontCondensedTrait),
    NSFontWeightTrait:   NSFontWeightBold,
//  NSFontWidthTrait:    1.0,
]
let descattr: [String: AnyObject] = [
    NSFontFamilyAttribute: "Gill Sans",
    NSFontSizeAttribute:   13,
    NSFontTraitsAttribute: traits,
]
var desc = NSFontDescriptor(fontAttributes: descattr)
//desc = desc.matchingFontDescriptorWithMandatoryKeys([NSFontFamilyAttribute, NSFontTraitsAttribute])!
let font = NSFont(descriptor: desc, size: 13)
print("\(font?.fontDescriptor)")
```

As is, this prints

```
Optional(NSCTFontDescriptor <0x7feb49535580> = {
    NSFontNameAttribute = "GillSans-BoldItalic";
    NSFontSizeAttribute = 13;
})
```

so it matches the bold flag and the weight value I specify.

However, if I add the Condensed trait, then the Bold and Italic traits stop registering and I just get regular old Gill Sans.

Same if I specify a weight of `NSFontWeightBlack` instead of 0 (`NSFontWeightRegular`), `NSFontWeightSemiBold`, or `NSFontWeightBold`.

Or in other words, both AppKit and Core Text (I independently verified this with Core Text) simply **ignore the traits dictionary** if there isn't an exact match.

How can I make it so that instead of ignoring the traits dictionary, it returns a font with the closest matching value for the specified trait in the dictionary? So for instance, if I pass `NSFontWeightBlack`, I should get the font for `NSFontWeightUltraBold` since that's the closest matching font.

Or am I going to have to implement such a matcher myself? (I don't mind doing this, and in fact I've already done so and it works fine; I'm just wondering if there's something I'm missing first.)

This is OS X 10.11, but I need to target OS X 10.7 and up.

Thanks.